# flutter : data to go over the curve parts when I scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

i post two images, first is looking good but when i am scrolling my data then my ui is getting messed up(second image)

I want it to go under the curve parts when I scroll.

HOW TO DO IT

This is my code

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: appGreenColor,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        backgroundColor: appGreenColor,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            "lib/Assets/bellazIcon.png",
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            height: 40,
            width: 78,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset(
                  "lib/Assets/notification1.png",
                  height: 22,
                  width: 22,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => NotificationList()));
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 70,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    locationView(),
                    imageSlider(),
                    genderView(),
                    categories(),
                    isMan == true
                        ? maleTopBranches.length == 0
                            ? Container()
                            : topRatedSalons(maleTopBranches)
                        : topRatedSalons(femaleTopBranches),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              offerImage(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    services(),
                    nearByAppointment(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              infoImage()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

this image looks fine till i am not scrolling

[image]

but when i scrolling image my data comes onto that curve

[image]

This answer work for me
adding : clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge

```
Container(
   clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 70,
   decoration: const BoxDecoration(
   color: Colors.white,
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30), 
                     topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
           child: ...,
         ),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add : clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge

```
Container(
   clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 70,
   decoration: const BoxDecoration(
   color: Colors.white,
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30), 
                     topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
           child: ...,
         ),)
```